# Make TabControl Headers Scrollable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar, tabcontrol

As Mentioned in Title, I want to change the header of my TabControl to be scrollable.

**The reason:** I have too many tabItems, and the wrapping is not the best solution in my case. so I want to change it from :

[image: Wrapping behaviour]

To something like that (Scroll bar indicated by the arrow) :

[image: scrolling behaviour]

Can anyone help me and show how to do that ? (I'm using wpf)

Comment: See [WPF: TabControl Series - Part 1: Colors and Sizes](http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/post/2010/01/25/TabControlStyling_PartOne.aspx).  Part 3 is where this blog talks about the scrolling issue.

Comment: @LarsTech it's not really what I want, there is no scroll bar, and his solution is complex ! Thank you for your comment

Comment: There's also [WPF Single Row Tab Control](http://rickdoes.net/post/2009/11/06/WPF-Single-Row-Tab-Control.aspx)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Changing `TabControl.Template` to something simple like this seems to work for me

```xml
<TabControl ...>
    <TabControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="4" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TabControl.Template>
</TabControl>
```