# How to prevent TabItems stacking up vertically when window size is reduced?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

As seen in this [image](http://tinypic.com/r/2sbo4d3/8), when I have a lot of tab items and resize the window so that the available space for tabitems is less than their width, the tab items start stacking up vertically. How do I prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make TabControl Headers Scrollable in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764401/make-tabcontrol-headers-scrollable-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of your TabControl and substitute the TabPanel with another container according to your needs (for example a StackPanel with Orientation Horizontal).

The TabPanel can stack items if the width is less than desidered.