ScrollViewer on TabControl hides contents
I can add scrolling over the tab items of a TabControl using information from this post: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/11896
However, a rather unfortunate side-effect is that the contents of the tab items disappear (in my sample xaml below, tab item 'One' should display 2 checkboxes but doesn't).
Here is simplified xaml which demonstrates the problem:
<TabControl Width="200">
    
    <!-- this allows scrolling through the tab items, but hides the tab item contents! --> 
    <TabControl.Styles>
        <Style Selector="TabControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Styles>
            
    <TabItem Header="One">
        <DockPanel>
            <!-- these are only visible if I remove the 'TabControl.Styles' section -->
            <CheckBox Content="First option"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Second option"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Two">
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Three">
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Four">
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Five">
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Six">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>


If you create a custom template for tabcontrol, then you should include an PART_ItemsPresenter and a PART_SelectedContentHost. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764401/make-tabcontrol-headers-scrollable-in-wpf but don't blindly copy from there ;)

I haven't created a custom template. The horizontal scrolling of the tab headers works (instead of the default wrapping), it's just the the contents disappear.

Tried suggestions from the link, but all that changed was the position of the scrollbar - tab contents still disappear.
